# Is there a faster way to perform this operation?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, 3d

I am calculating the distance between every point of an array and a certain point, is there a faster way than to create a loop? This calculation can take me up to an hour for 3D matrices of size 100x100x100 I'm sure there's a faster way to do it, I just can't figure it out.

```
phi = np.zeros_like(i).astype(float)
ri2 = np.array((int(2*N/5) , int(N/2), int(N/2)))
ri1 = np.array((int(3*N/5) , int(N/2), int(N/2)))
for index, a in np.ndenumerate(phi):
    x,y,z = index
    phi[(i==x)&(j==y)&(k==z)] = 1/np.linalg.norm(index-ri2) + 1/np.linalg.norm(np.array(index - ri1))
```

Comment: What are i, j, and k? What is the certain point you're getting the distance from?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have i,j and k such that k, j, i = np.mgrid[:N, :N, :N] I am getting the distance from two points : ri1 and ri2

Comment: Never create a loop. Just for reference (the function you need is not included) , there is a distance module in [scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/spatial.distance.html)

Comment: Please complete you example code, so others can fully understand the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must always avoid looping through arrays. Numpy is fast doing that, and plain python is very slow. If you use vectorized operations and functions, you will get the speed you want. Here is an example calculating the distance from an array of 10x10x10 points to a point whose position is stored in `r1`. The first part of the code is just setup, the last part is what matters to you:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Let's create the array with point coordinates
N = 10
x = np.linspace(0, 100, N)
X, Y, Z = (coord.flatten() for coord in np.meshgrid(x, x, x))
# now X, Y and Z have the respective coordinates of each of the N**3 points
# Let' see it visually (don't do this for N=100)
fig = plt.figure("Positions")
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
ax.scatter(X, Y, Z)

# put everything in one array, so `pos` has the positions of the N**3 points
pos = np.stack((X, Y, Z), axis=-1)
# define the point of interest: we will calculate the distances to this point
r1 = np.array((20, 20, 20))

# Now perform the calculation: vector difference, square of each axis,
# sum of the squares and square root of the sum. All in one line because we can
dist= np.sqrt(np.sum(np.square(pos - r1), axis=1)) # Euclidean distance


# Now we are done. Let's represent the distance with a color code
fig = plt.figure("Distance")
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
sc = ax.scatter(X, Y, Z, c=dist)
plt.colorbar(sc)
```

Result:
[image: Color-coded distance to (20, 20, 20)]